# Convert object constraints to keyframes?

Tags: keyframes, constraints

I have a camera object that has a track to and a follow path constraint on it, which serve as a mean to animate it on a curve, and tell it where to look.

However, I'm using an add-on called Flares Wizard, which has features that doesn't seem to work if the camera has basically any constraints on it, or is parented to anything. But keyframes are fine.

The camera doesn't actually have any location+rotation transforms on it, all of it's values are zeroed out, all transforms are done visually via the constraints. So my question is, can I somehow turn these constraints into LocRot keyframes on the actual camera itself?

Thanks for any help!

Here's a simplified demo file:

[image]

Comment: There is a function for this, called "Bake Action": https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/actions.html#bake-action

Comment: Thanks! But that's not a solution unfortunately, I've already tried that. As I said, the camera doesn't have any animations on it, on the constraints that are on the camera, so when I bake the action it just comes out empty, nothing happens.

Comment: I've added a simplified blend file.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine, just check in "Clear Constraints" and "Visual Keying" on the pop-up panel.

Comment: Yes! visual keying is the one I needed. Thanks a lot!